# Filtering Input files

Tags: bash, perl

So I'm trying to filter 'duplicate' results from a file.

Ive a file that looks like:

```
7 14 35 35 4 23
23 53 85 27 49 1
35 4 23 27 49 1
....
```

that I mentally can divide up into item 1 and item 2. Item 1 is the first 3 numbers on each line and item 2 is the last 3 numbers on each line.

I've also got a list of 'items':

```
7 14 35
23 53 85
35 4 23
27 49 1
...
```

At a certain point in the file, lets say line number 3 (this number is arbitrary and for example), the 'items' can be separated. Lets say lines 1 and 2 are red and lines 3 and 4 are blue.

I want to make sure on my original file that there are no red red or blue blues - only red blue or blue red, while retaining the original numbers. 
So ideally the file would go from:

```
7 14 35 35 4 23 (red blue)
23 53 85 27 49 1 (red blue)
35 4 23 27 49 1 (blue blue)
....
```

to

```
7 14 35 35 4 23 (red blue)
23 53 85 27 49 1 (red blue)
....
```

I'm having trouble thinking of a good (or any) way to do it. 
Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

An filtering script I have that grabs lines if they have blue or red on the lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read name; do
  grep "$name" Twoitems
done < Itemblue > filtered

while read name2; do
  grep "$name2" filtered
done < Itemred > double filtered
```

EDIT2:

Example input an item files:

Comment: And what determines whether a line is red or blue? What have you tried so far? Post some code.

Comment: I think you don't want two consecutive lines from file2 to exist in file1 in a line?

Comment: @AruneshSingh After a certain arbitrary number of lines (2 in the example) in the item list the items change from being red to blue. Ive got a file that has two items per row. I only want rows that have mixed color items on them. If that clarifies at all?

Comment: But as Matt Jacob asked `what determines whether a line is red or blue?`

Comment: @MattJacob I've added what I have.

Comment: @AruneshSingh Lets say the items list is 105 lines long, and therefore has 105 items. Let's say the first 35 are red and the last 70 are blue. The only thing that determines their color is if they are the first 35 or the last 70.

Comment: OK... and how is the cutoff determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy using `grep` with option `-f`.

First of all, generate four 'pattern' files out of your items file.
I am using AWK here, but you might as well use Perl or what not.
Following your example, I put the 'split' between line 2 and 3; please adjust when necessary.

```
awk 'NR <= 2 {print "^" $0 " "}' items.txt > starts_red.txt
awk 'NR <= 2 {print " " $0 "$"}' items.txt > ends_red.txt

awk 'NR >= 3 {print "^" $0 " "}' items.txt > starts_blue.txt
awk 'NR >= 3 {print " " $0 "$"}' items.txt > ends_blue.txt
```

Next, use a `grep` pipeline using the pattern files (option `-f`) to filter the appropriate lines from the input file.

```
grep -f starts_red.txt  input.txt | grep -f ends_blue.txt > red_blue.txt
grep -f starts_blue.txt input.txt | grep -f ends_red.txt  > blue_red.txt
```

Finally, concatenate the two output files.
Of course, you might as well use `>>` to let the second `grep` pipeline append its output to the output of the first.

Comment: The way you went about it gave me a good idea of how to accomplish the goal in perl, but I couldn't get the implementation of yours to work right. The starts and ends files never seem to have the right length of lines to them.

Comment: I've updated my question with example files. For the life of me, I cannot figure out why it doesn't work. The start and end files are fine - I was mistaken about that being an issue. Sorry. The entire thing also works perfectly if the example files in the original question are used, but due to some operator error that escapes me I can't make it work on a real file.

Comment: @jcklasseter Thanks for the sample data! I got it working by stripping off the trailing space from every line in `input.txt`. Splitting items between line 75 and 76 (I had to guess that), resulted in 354 lines (177 red/blue, 177 blue/red). If you like, I can adjust the AWK scripts to cater for leading/trailing/double spaces.

Comment: Its okay! I do about enough modification steps before I Get to this point to these files where a quick line to remove trailing spaces is no problem to put elsewhere. Thanks for the help! I appreciate it!

Comment: Question: the AWK part puts all of the reds into red pattern files and all of the blue into the blue pattern files. If we split at 50, shouldn't the red pattern files be 50 rows long and the blue be 100 rows long? When I run it I get both red pattern files as 20 rows long and the blues at 131 rows long.

Comment: Again, its probably user error. I'm using $1 and $2 for the start and end conditions and running the program like: (./foo 50 51) if that helps at all. Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: @jcklasseter It's because `$1` will not expand within single quotes. This should work (I didn't test it yet): `awk "NR <= $1"'{print "^" $0 " "}' ...`

Answer (score 1):

Let's say file1 contents

```
7 14 35 35 4 23
23 53 85 27 49 1
35 4 23 27 49 1
```

and file2 contents are

```
7 14 35
23 53 85
35 4 23
27 49 1
```

Then, you can use a hash to map line-nos to colors based on your `cutoff` and using that hash, compare lines in first file for the existence of different colors after splitting on third space of each line.

I suppose you want something like below script.Feel free to modify it according to your requirements.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#declare a global hash to keep track of line and colors
my %color;

#open both the files     
open my $fh1, '<', 'file1' or die "unable to open file1: $! \n";
open my $fh2, '<', 'file2' or die "unable to open file2: $! \n";

#iterate over the second file and store the lines as
#red or blue in hash based on line nos
while(<$fh2>){
        chomp;
        if($. <= 2){
        $color{$_}="red";
        }
        else{
           $color{$_}="blue";
        }
}
#close second file
close($fh2);

#iterate over first file
while(<$fh1>){
      chomp;
      #split the line on 3rd space 
      my ($part1,$part2)=split /(?:\d+\s){3}\K/;
      #remove trailing spaces present 
      $part1=~s/\s+$//;
      #print if $part1 and $part does not belong to same color
      print "$_\n" if($color{$part1} ne $color{$part2});
}
#close first file
close($fh1);
```